# Missing arguments that shouldn't be missing(Python)?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm currently writing a simple "combat algorithm"(if that's the term for it) that will eventually be built up to be more and more complex, but right now the most it needs to calculate is damage done, current health points, and chance of a dodge. Here is the code itself:

```
#paradisium combat algorithm 1.0
import random
#ranged speed
player1_attack=5
#damage to enemy is attack-defense points
player1_defence=2
player1_speed=9
#higher speed higher chance to land a hit
player1_agility=9
#higher agility, higher chance of dodge
player1_HP=50
#two-handed defense
player2_attack=9
player2_defence=9
#blocking raises defense by doubling it
player2_speed=5
player2_agility=2
player2_HP=100
def player1attack(player1_speed,player1_attack,player2_agility,player2_defence,player2_HP,damage):
    dogeChance=player2_agility-player1_speed
    if random.randint(0,100)>dogeChance:
         damage=player1_attack-player2_defence
         player2_HP-=damage
         return (player2_HP, damage)
while player1_HP>0 or player2_HP>0:
    askMove=input("Attack(1) Brace(2)")
    if askMove=="1":
         damage=0
         player1attack(player1_speed,player1_attack,player2_agility,player2_defence,player2_HP,damage)
         damage,player2_HP=player1attack(damage,player2_HP)
         print("Player 2 recieved",damage,"damage!")
         print("Player 2's HP is at",player2_HP+"!")}
```

As you can see, I simply just listed all the stats variables at the beginning. The program will eventually be able to take in the stats of whatever two people are fighting, and put those into the algorithm.
The current math behind behind this algorithm is that damage to a person's HP is only dealt if you fail to dodge an attack, the dodge chance(yes I named it dogeChance on purpose) is calculated by subtracting the attacker's speed from the defender's agility(in this case player 2's agility minus player 1's speed, since that's as far as we've gotten).
Damage is calculated similarly by subtracting defense minus attack, the remaining number being the damage dealt to the enemy.
The issue I'm having though is that although all of the variables required are listed in the beginning of the program, I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/combatAlgorithmParadisium.py", line 30, in <module>
    damage,player2_HP=player1attack(damage,player2_HP)
TypeError: player1attack() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'player2_agility', 'player2_defence', 'player2_HP', and 'damage'
```

What I'm getting from this is that the function is not taking in the arguments it needs to, so I don't know if I'm making a rookie mistake or what. As you can see, this design is very simple. I've been on the novice level for programming in general for a while so I apologize in advance if I can't understand your explanation. I've also changed the variable names so they're easier to read and identify.

With thanks, Rusty Manibus

Comment: `player1atk` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted ...

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I'll edit that right away.
Edit: Fixed it, I had run the program again to get the same error with the different variable names, but had accidentally copied a different error message.

Comment: You call player1attack twice. The second one has too few parameters. Its on line 30 of your program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest using object classes to make this code considerably more readable as well as ultimately more useable and maintainable.

Here's my attempt to translate your code into something "classier:"

```
#!python
## !/usr/bin/env python3
import random

class Player (object):
    def __init__(self, attack, defence, speed, agility, hitpoints):
        self.attack    = attack
        self.defence   = defence
        self.speed     = speed
        self.agility   = agility
        self.hitpoints = hitpoints

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.hitpoints > 0

    def Attack(self, target):
        dodgeChance = target.agility - self.speed
        damage = 0
        roll = random.randint(0,100)
        if roll > dodgeChance:
             damage = abs(self.attack - target.defence)
        target.hitpoints -= damage
        return (target.hitpoints, damage, dodgeChance, roll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    player1 = Player(5, 2, 9, 9, 50)
    player2 = Player(9, 9, 5, 2, 100)

    while player1.is_alive() or player2.is_alive():
        damage = dodge = roll = 0
        askMove = input("Attack(1) Brace(2)")
        if askMove.startswith("1"):
             damage, x, dodge, roll = player1.Attack(player2)
        player2.Attack(player1)
        print("Player 2 recieved", damage, "damage!")
        print("Player 2's HP is at %s!" % player2.hitpoints)
        print("\t\tDodge: %s\tRoll: %s!" % (dodge, roll))
        print("\tPlayer 1 HP: %s\n" % (player1.hitpoints))
```

Incidentally, in older versions of Python input() returns a result based on the Python *evaluation* of a line of input (from standard input).  Thus entering *`1`*[Enter] results in an integer 1 rather than a string: "1" --- in your code the `askMove == "1"` condition will NEVER be met (under Python 2.x). (Note, the duplicate #! lines in my pasted code are to distinguish between my running copy of the code and the shebang line that makes SO's syntax highlighter happy).

Also my initial translation of your code seemed to run forever (for almost? all cases).  We have to take the absolute value of the damage result in order to ensure that the hit points are always decreasing in this simulation.  The choice of keeping the `while` loop going so long as *either* of the players still lives is odd ... since the dead player continues to fight and the living player (who should be victorious) continues to fight the zombie until he, too, is dead.

(Not exactly the game mechanics I'd recommend).

Also please forgive the use of `.attack` as a field name and `.Attack()` as a method.  I wanted to keep terms in my translation of your code as close to your as possible.  In my own code I would have probably named the field/attribute ".attack_bonus" or even just ".bonus" depending on how many other attributes I intend to support in the future.

Comment: Huh, didn't know you could do this with python. I'll try using object classes more often then. I hope you wouldn't mind if I copy-pasted the code so I could work with it and figure it out more? I forget if that's against the site's rules. And I don't have much reputation, so sorry I can't upvote, but again I found this very helpful.

Comment: This code is free for all uses.  I hereby declare it to be public domain.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate  on `is_alive` for me? Specifically `return self.hitpoints`? I can't tell if you're using the `return` statement as some sort conditional to break the while loop, or if that's not really anything.

Comment: In Python any non-zero numeric value and any non-empty container (list, tuple, dictionary, set or string) is evaluated as True in a boolean context.  Zero and empty are effectively False for conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

```
 player1attack(player1_speed,player1_attack,player2_agility,player2_defence,player2_HP,damage)
 damage,player2_HP=player1attack(damage,player2_HP)
```

`player1attack` takes six parameters. In the above code, you use the correct number of parameters on the first line. On the second line, you're not passing enough parameters. You're passing two of the required six, hence the `missing 4` error. In any case, I'm not sure why you're calling the function twice. I say, just combine the lines, using the best qualities from either one (the "correct number of parameters" from the first line, and the "assigns the result to some variables" from the second).

```
damage, player2_HP = player1attack(player1_speed, player1_attack, player2_agility, player2_defence, player2_HP, damage)
```

Comment: So this calls the function as well as returning the two variables `damage` and `player2_HP` so that they can be used outside of the function? Edit: I don't have enough reputation so I can't upvote your post, but I did find it very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What Kevin said. Also `damage` and `player2_HP` are being asigned the wrong values on line

```
damage,player2_HP=player1attack(damage,player2_HP)
```

since your function is designed to return `player2_HP` first and `damage` second.

Lastly, in its current state your algorithm makes player 2 earn more HP with each hit as you're substracting a negative integer which thus makes a positive. I suggest the following edit to avoid that:

```
damage=player1_attack-player2_defence if player1_attack-player2_defence > 0 else 0
```

However, this is still not satisfaying, as it means Player 2 will never get any damage as they're too strong in defense. Maybe you shouldn't substract the entire defense points to the attack points but only a fraction of them.

(Edit: I've also just noticed that your algoithm uses a negative dogeChance)

(I wanted to post all this as a side comment but I don't have commenting priviledges yet)

Comment: `damage=player1_attack-player2_defence if player1_attack-player2_defence > 0 else 0` I didn't know you could put in `if` statements like that, thanks. How do you suggest I fix the negative `dogeChance`? Edit: I also don't have much reputation, so I can't upvote your post.